# water refraction

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I am a beginner user of blender and I hope that stack exchange not only is for experts.
I like to "make" a swimming pool in blender / eevee with water and refraction , without animation and without rendering .
It works with the glass BSDF or with the principled BSDF , but there is always a dirty grey "shadow" appearing .
The only way to get rid of that "shadow" is to disable refraction .
I suppose that it will only be possible with compositor and rendering , but I dont want to render .
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Hello, could you please show a screenshot to show what you mean? maybe share your file?

Comment: Reflections and refraction interacts with ALL that is visible in the scene, including the background that is grey by default. But if you don't want to render, then why do you care about how your shading reflects its environment? What are you trying to achieve?